# Как проверить запущен ли сервер nodejs + express

Tags: node.js, express

Как убедиться с помощью кода что сервер уже был запущен после 
    var app = express();

```
app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function() {
       console.log('server start');      
})
```

Edit

Фишка в том что мне нужно програмно именно проверить работает ли сервер и express типа `server.isRun()`

Comment: что значит убедится, что был запущен?

Comment: @modelfak, а зачем это проверять?) Вам нужен какой-то инструмент мониторинга или что?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Когда пробую тестировать  `rest api` с помощью `mocha + chai` на express то сервер может быть запущен уже и тогда я получаю ошибку

Comment: А почему бы не вынести весь REST сервер в отдельный изолированный модуль и запускать его в `before` хуке Mocha.js? Это позволит запускать тесты только тогда, когда (и если) ваш сервер уже поднялся.

Comment: Рядом с console.log напишите `app.isStarted = true;`

Comment: Хотя, там уже должна быть переменная [app.listening](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listening)

Comment: Неужели он исключение не бросает? E_ADDR_IN_USE или как оно там?

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('ready to go!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http.createServer(app).listen(config.get('port'), function(){
  console.info('Express server listening on port ' + config.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: ну запущен да а как потом проверить что он запущен? )

Comment: Так в вывод же в консоль будет.

Comment: ну это понятно что будет вывод ) а вот проверить например в другом сервисе запущен ли этот

Comment: читай выше.....

Comment: эээ... ну пинг... нет?

Comment: пинг смотрите в вопросе пинг... типа если у тебя машина заведена - проверь гудит ли двигатель )))

Comment: Я имел в веду, что можно в твоем внешнем сервисе, обернуть код в if(коннект к серверу){то что то делаем}else{консоле.лог(сервер не достпен)}; Чего вы еще хотите то?

Answer (score 0):

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
   console.log('Express server lintening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```